# Facebook Connect - simply add a user's Facebook profile url into database via Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I'm coding a simple app which should use some FB connect mechanics but I don't want too much overhead here so maybe you can share your thoughts/experience on my task:

- merchants can post products they want to give away for free
- users can register for the article and get into a raffle

Once a user enters the page, I want the page to connect to his FB profile URL (facebook.com/username). User hits a "Add me to the raffle" button, the FB profile URL gets stored into my model. The merchant or a cron choses the FB profile URL randomly, displays it and lets the merchant connect to the winner (this I realised already).

This is what I've done so far:
http://limitless-brook-6233.herokuapp.com/ads/1

as you can see, I realised it via email addresses which get shuffled by the merchant. This is not very clever since FB profiles are somehow more unique and everyone can participate only one time.

What is the smartest way in your opinion to retrieve a user's Facebook URL and store it into my database? I just need to attach it to some text/input field (non editable) and let the user hit that button.

Thanks for any support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Facebook login, take a look here
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/
or here
https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook
for the second one use version 1.4.0 as 1.4.1 has ome annoying bugs.